# How to time-shift audio on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

This is similar to [The Pitch Shift question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone), except I want to keep my audio at the same pitch, but play it slower or faster -- time shift it.  (On the iPhone.)

Can anyone point me to a library, tutorial or other reading to help with that?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using the Dirac library, which handles this problem quite nicely.  Maybe someday I'll learn all about FFTs and implement that on my own.

http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this essentially the same thing? For example, if you pitch-shift something up an octave, then play it back at half speed, then it will play at the original pitch, but last twice as long...

Comment: Right.  The question is: how to play it back at half speed.  "Just modify the sound samples" isn't a detailed enough answer for me to follow what needs to be done.

Comment: @Olie - I didn't say "Just modify the sound samples" :-) How to change the playback rate depends on what API you're using to play the audio, but if you're using one that uses the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` structure, you may be able to modify the `mSampleRate` element to adjust the playback rate. Have you tried out any of the solutions from the "Pitch Shift" question yet? Which API did you use to play the sounds?

Comment: Ah, yes -- sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you said that, only that it's a common theme in other answers I've seen, and I'm not quite up to the level of being able to interpret that sort of glossing-over.

I'm not currently tied to any particular playback mechanism, as tempo-shifting is a necessary component.  I'll investigate the AudioStream stuff.

To the answer you gave: "If you pitch shift something up an octave" -- how?  "...then play it back at half speed" -- how?  That's what I was getting at.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A "time shift" is simply a delay. "Time Stretching" is what you will want, which is the reciprocal case to pitch shifting. As others have mentioned, Dirac should fit the bill.