# Change Accent of the voice recorded+ iPhone

Tags: iphone, voice

I have googled this thing but am unable to find the answer.
What I have to do is I have to record a sound using iPhone and have to replay it using different accents(British,UK etc...)

Is there any API available or is there any framework provided by Apple to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a research topic in speech processing for which you might have to do a lot of reading of academic papers.

There is no API for this, other than for generic audio IO and DSP functions.

Comment: have a look at the application **talking cat** . It uses some different funny accent and repeats our sound. Also there are several other applications one of them is **British Accent** They too are doing the same.

Comment: The talking cat app just does a fixed time pitch change, like speaking with helium in your lungs, nothing to do with accents.  Changing pitch is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone

Comment: and what about the british accent?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any API available or is there any framework provided by Apple to do this.

I'm struggling to think of why Apple would provide an API for this, or why anyone else would for that matter! There aren't exactly many use cases.

Voice recognition systems have a hard enough time trying to understand heavily accented dialects, so what you're asking is computationally difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: have a look at the application talking cat. It uses some different funny accent and repeats our sound. Also there are several other applications one of them is **British Accent** They too are doing the same.