# Easiest way to play music at higher pitch in iOS?

Tags: ios

I suppose there's a lot of tutorials everywhere on the proper way to play .mp3 music for your game on iOS, but is it possible to effectively play music at higher pitch in iOS?

What I mean with effectively, is not by loading the .mp3 file as a whole into memory, like when playing little bits of .wav files that are shorter than a few seconds. Unless, this kind of preloading is necessary for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAl has pitch shifting with AL_PITCH.

more info about AL_PITCH and other methods here

[Real-time Pitch Shifting on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone)