# change sound pitch (not in realtime)

Tags: iphone, audio, avfoundation, pitch

i alway had this question in my mind, but wherever i asked, i could never get an answer or a suggestion that would be helpful:

How can i pitch a sound (not realtime) ?

Im using AVFoundation framework to play my sounds like so:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:TempRecFile error:nil];
    player.volume = 1;
    [player play];
```

How can i set the pitch or the frequency of my sound without having to use some othere frameworks like OpenAL. Although, if you know a place where i could learn some OpenAl you're very welcome :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few iPhone time-pitch shifting libraries mentioned the this StackOverflow answer: [Real-time Pitch Shifting on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone),
which work offline as well as potentially in real-time.

Here's a [wikipedia article on time-pitch technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_timescale-pitch_modification), and a [dspdimention overview on the topic](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/).