# real time pitch change in iphone using dirac

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real-time Pitch Shifting on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone)

i have already found the answer of my question:
whether the real time pitch change possible in iphone?
[Real-time Pitch Shifting on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone)
but i want to ask that there is no problem with the use of dirac library in the AppStore to submit the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple apps that use Dirac (both the free LE and the commercial Pro) on the App store inluding some I have co-authored, so you should be fine.