# Auto record the voice when user speaks in iPhone and playback the voice

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real-time Pitch Shifting on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone)

hi i am new to iPhone programming .Here i am going to develop a application like tomcat.So when user starts talking recorder should record and playback with funny voice.So anyone please help me out.