# How can I play a sound file with varying pitch in iOS device programmatically

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I have a heart beat sound file. I would like to play it on increasing pitch as a user waits for a time interval to finish. Can anyone tell me how to do this in iOS ?

Comment: Based on some (very cursory) searching: [have you looked into DIRAC](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html) at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to see:  [Real-time Pitch Shifting on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone)

That article references dirac3d, but CoreAudio also now has this capability but it's non-trivial to setup. Chris Adamson has written some good articles on CoreAudio that would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of iOS includes, built-in, the NewTimePitch Audio Unit, which can be used for increasing the pitch or play time independently.