# How can I change the recorded voices into fun voices in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-audio, avfoundation

I have seen some iPhone apps in which recorded voices are made into fun voices. Is it possible to programmatically change recorded voices into fun voices using an iOS library?

I found some app like Voices 2 ~ fun voice changing!, Talking Tom etc. How do they do it?

Comment: The theory is probably very dependent on the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).  I wouldn't bet on a library being available in ObjC.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I didn't get you.

Comment: @Madan: what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @Michael:Can we change the recoded voice into funny voices using core audio and AVFoundation.

Comment: @Madan: I merely cleaned up your question. I don't have an answer for you. Do you mean to address bdares?

Comment: @bdares While there might not be a high level Objective-C library for what the OP wants, iOS 4 does include the Accelerate framework. This framework provides FFT (and other, mostly DSP-related) functions.

Comment: @bdares: I didn't get you. Can you explain it clearly. Can we change the recoded voice using FFT

Comment: Fourier Transforms basically decomposes signals (sound waves, in our case) into their frequencies.  It becomes much easier to manipulate them, after which we can transform them back into regular old sound waves, which are hopefully "fun".

Comment: Accelerate.framework contains FFTs in the vDSP library. This is available on iOS and Mac

Answer (score 1):

It looks like OpenAL could give you what you want, and there are other options: See [here](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html) and [here](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035975/how-do-you-completely-remove-and-release-memory-of-an-openal-sound-file/4647692#4647692).

Answer (score 0):

Talking Tom uses Dirac I think: http://dirac.dspdimension.com. They have a free LE version as well (should be sufficient for voice processing).